# Checking instanceof in node.js addons using Nan

Tags: javascript, node.js, node.js-addon, node.js-nan

I am trying to verify that an object passed to a node addon is of the correct type before I unwrap it and start to use it. Here's the solution that I've cobbled together from looking at various sources on the web.

Persistent data:

```
Nan::Persistent<v8::Function> Event::constructor;
Nan::Persistent<v8::FunctionTemplate> Event::tpl;
```

The Init function:

```
void Event::Init(v8::Local<v8::Object> exports) {
    Nan::HandleScope scope;

    // Prepare constructor template
    v8::Local<v8::FunctionTemplate> ctor = Nan::New<v8::FunctionTemplate>(Event::New);
    ctor->InstanceTemplate()->SetInternalFieldCount(1);
    ctor->SetClassName(Nan::New("Event").ToLocalChecked());

    // create a template for checking instances
    Local<FunctionTemplate> localTemplate = Nan::New<FunctionTemplate>(Event::New);
    localTemplate->SetClassName(Nan::New("Event").ToLocalChecked());
    tpl.Reset(localTemplate);

    // Statics
    Nan::SetMethod(ctor, "x", Event::X);

    // Prototype
    Nan::SetPrototypeMethod(ctor, "addInfo", Event::addInfo);
    Nan::SetPrototypeMethod(ctor, "toString", Event::toString);

    constructor.Reset(ctor->GetFunction());
    Nan::Set(exports, Nan::New("Event").ToLocalChecked(), ctor->GetFunction());
}
```

And where I attempt to use it:

```
    if (Nan::New(tpl)->HasInstance(info[0])) {
        message = "it is an Event instance";
    }
```

The problem is that the `HasInstance()` never returns true.

The JavaScript code is basically

```
let e = new Event()
fn(e)     // where fn performs the HasInstance() test.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to make a second `FunctionTemplate`. The one you've set on the exports (`ctor`) is the one that gets used when you call `new Event()` in JS, while the second one (`localTemplate`) gets saved to `Event::tpl` and is the one from which the `HasInstance()` call gets made. They're different `FunctionTemplate`s, so the `HasInstance()` call returns `false`.

Instead of this:

```cpp
...
Local<FunctionTemplate> localTemplate = Nan::New<FunctionTemplate>(Event::New);
localTemplate->SetClassName(Nan::New("Event").ToLocalChecked());
tpl.Reset(localTemplate);
...
```

just try this:

```js
...
tpl.Reset(ctor);
...
```

Comment: I'd solved the problem as you suggested but forgot I'd asked the question. There's not much Nan/NAPI focus here. But your answer is spot on and helpful! Thanks.